# How to extend AlertDialog.Builder result?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, builder

I need to show an `AlertDialog` with a `ListView` and a context menu for the `ListView` items. I prefer to use `AlertDialog.Builder` and call `setItems()`, so the `Builder` creates a `ListView` inside the `AlertDialog` with stylized layout for me. For the stylizing it uses internal Android resources, so I cannot reimplement it in my code.

The problem is that I cannot catch a context menu item click event because of default [`AlertDialog.onMenuItemSelected()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/app/Dialog.java#Dialog.onMenuItemSelected%28int%2Candroid.view.MenuItem%29) implementation, which does not forward such events to the parent:

```
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    return false;
}
```

I cannot extend `AlertDialog.Builder` class and force it to create an instance of my own `AlertDialog` with `onMenuItemSelected()` overridden because I need to override [`AlertDialog.Builder.create()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/app/AlertDialog.java#AlertDialog.Builder.create%28%29) for that. But it uses a private `P` variable, which is not accessible from a derived class:

```
    public AlertDialog create() {
        final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog(P.mContext, mTheme, false);
        P.apply(dialog.mAlert);
        dialog.setCancelable(P.mCancelable);
        if (P.mCancelable) {
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        }
        dialog.setOnCancelListener(P.mOnCancelListener);
        if (P.mOnKeyListener != null) {
            dialog.setOnKeyListener(P.mOnKeyListener);
        }
        return dialog;
    }
```

Is there a way to force `AlertDialog.Builder` to construct a custom `AlertDialog` (with `onMenuItemSelected` method overridden)?

Comment: Your question is a little ambiguous. You speak about implementing a  `ContextMenu` but you're referring to the `onMenuItemSelected` callback. Also, I hope I understand, you're trying to show a `ContextMenu` for the elements in an `AlertDialog` list? If yes, I would recommend to not do this because it will feel very awkward for the user. Also the `AlertDialog` class is just a simple dialog to be show it isn't designed for extension(as the parent class is more suited for this).

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. I referring to `onMenuItemSelected` because it is the method you need to use to handle context menu clicks in a dialog (instead of `onContextItemSelected`). I have a set of filters in my application. I let a user to choose a filter with the `AlertDialog`. I need to let the user to remove a filter from the list. As for me the best way is to use 'delete' context menu item. Do you know where can I find the actual code for context menu event dispatching? Where the actual implementation of `ContextMenu` interface? Thanks.

Comment: I would strongly recommend creating your own `Dialog` consisting of a `ListView` with the filters items. I would also put a small remove `Button` on each row which will trigger the removal of that filter. The `ContextMenu` is handled by the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still found no solution for the question, but I found some problems, which makes the solution useless. For Android 2.1, built-in `ListView` items (android.R.layout.select_dialog_item) are displayed as black text on dark grey background, `ListView` items are not separated from the dialog message (`setMessage()`), etc.

I finally switched back to my own `AlertDialog` with custom layout for `ListView` and its items (`AlertDialog.Builer` not used). Context menu events can be easily catched this way.

Luksprog, thanks a lot for your comments. But the main idea was to use as many stylized layouts, as possible. AFAIK, no standard layouts (`android.R.layout.*`) offer the buttons you mentioned. Also, an item could be removed occasionally with the button. With a context menu, at least two click required to remove an item.

Comment: Black on dark grey text of ListView was a side effect of setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Light) for _another_ (?!) activity (not the primary activity, which calls the dialog). Any way, I will be happy to accept any answer, which solves the original question.